# javascript- unable to convert canvas to image data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

guys!

I'm trying to make a demo using which a user will be able to capture an image from the web camera enabled through his browser and this image will be saved in the backend by passing it to a PHP service using AJAX call.

I'm able to capture as canvas but not being to convert it into image data.
I'm getting `canvas is undefined error`

Setup is pretty simple.

**HTML**

```
<video id="videoElement"  autoplay></video>
<button id="snap">Snap Photo</button>
<canvas id="canvas" style="display:none" ></canvas>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
    // Grab elements, create settings, etc.
    var video = document.getElementById('videoElement');

    // Get access to the camera!
    if(navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
        // Not adding `{ audio: true }` since we only want video now
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true }).then(function(stream) {
            video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
            video.play();
        });
    }

    // Elements for taking the snapshot
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var video = document.getElementById('videoElement');

    // Trigger photo take
    document.getElementById("snap").addEventListener("click", function() {
      var cann= context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480); //draw canvas
    //then convert canvas to image so i can obtain dataurl
    //and pass it to another function using AJAX
      var img= convertCanvasToImage(cann);
    console.log(img);
    });

// Converts canvas to an image
function convertCanvasToImage(canvas) 
{
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    return image;
}
```

I'm pretty new to this field. I have one more question. Will this work on latest browsers? 
Can anyone help me figure out the mistake I made?

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/gb3ytqdx/1/)

Reference: 
https://davidwalsh.name/browser-camera

https://davidwalsh.name/convert-canvas-image

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just call this

```
 var img= convertCanvasToImage();

function convertCanvasToImage() 
{
  var image = new Image();
  image.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  return image;
}
```

No need to pass canvas as you defined canvas above. But if you have convertCanvasToImage function in another file then you can use

```
var img= convertCanvasToImage(canvas);
```

Comment: It's in the same file.

Comment: Then first solution is best for you :) . Hope it heloped you

Comment: Is there a way to improve the quality of the captured shot? It's of poor quality now. @Manoj Lodhi

Comment: @SajeevC define "poor quality"? The quality depends on your webcam

Comment: yes you can do with canvas.toDataURL("image/png", qualityValue); .

Comment: Image is blurry. I have used the same web camera to capture better quality image @Oscar Siauw

Comment: The default value of quality it takes is 0.92. So you can use 1.0 for some better quality.

Answer (score 1):

This may help.

```
function demoFromHTML() {
    html2canvas(document.getElementById("talltweets"), {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            var imageData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png',1.0); 

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What does 1.0 indicate in var imageData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png',1.0); @chirag

Comment: It is indicate a image resolution of genrating images

Comment: is 1.0 the highest value it can take? @chirag

Comment: Yes 1.0 is the highest value.

Comment: The default value of quality it takes is 0.92.  So you can use 1.0 for some better quality.

Comment: Yes, you can adjust as per your required.

Answer (score 0):

Pass `canvas` object instead of `cann`

```
var img= convertCanvasToImage(canvas);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can try to avoid dataURL and use blob instead - it will save you more memory and [load images faster](https://jsfiddle.net/fdzmd4mg/2/)

```js
$canvas.toBlob(function(blob){
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
  var img = new Image

  img.onload = function() {
    URL.revokeObjecURL(this.src)
  }
  img.src = url
  
  console.log(blob)
  console.log(url)
})
```

```html
<canvas id="$canvas">
```

there is polyfills you can use to support canvas#toBlob